# While loop stops at first iteration

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I'm trying to add all the numbers for matching arrays and remove the duplicate names. It works for the first instance, but the while loop won't go past Apples.

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {

   function alphabetizer(a, b) {
   if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
   if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
   return 0;
   }

  var newInv = arr1.concat(arr2).sort(alphabetizer);


  for(i=0;i<newInv.length;i++){

    while(newInv[i][1] != -1){
      newInv[i][0] += newInv[i+1][0];
      newInv.push([newInv[i][0], newInv[i][1]]);
      newInv.splice(i,2);
      return newInv;
    }
    return newInv;
  }

    return newInv;
}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"],
    [10, "Apples"]
];

var newInv = [
    [9, "Apples"],
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

So when I run this I just end up getting

```
[[21,"Bowling Ball"],[67,"Bowling Ball"],[2,"Dirty Sock"],[1,"Hair Pin"],[2,"Hair Pin"],[3,"Half-Eaten Apple"],[5,"Microphone"],[7,"Toothpaste"],[19,"Apples"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got it working, adding `var j = i` and changing some code.

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {

    function alphabetizer(a, b) {
        if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
        if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;

        return 0;    
    }

    var newInv = arr1.concat(arr2).sort(alphabetizer);

    for (var i = 0; i < newInv.length; i++) {
        var j = i;
        while (newInv[j + 1] && newInv[j][1] == newInv[j + 1][1]) {
            newInv[j][0] += newInv[j + 1][0];
            newInv.splice(j + 1, 1);
            j++;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = newInv.join('<br>');
}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"],
    [10, "Apples"]
];

var newInv = [
    [9, "Apples"],
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you are returning from the `while` loop. It terminates the further execution of the loop. Remove `return` part from the `for` and `while` loops. And also declare variable `i` with `var` keyword to make it scoped to the function, not global.

```
for(var i = 0; i < newInv.length; i++) {

    while(newInv[i][1] != -1) {

      newInv[i][0] += newInv[i+1][0];
      newInv.push([newInv[i][0], newInv[i][1]]);
      newInv.splice(i,2);

    }

}
```

Comment: I did it like this, but was getting 'TypeError: newInv[i] is undefined' even after adding the 'var' which is what I think I was missing earlier. Adding in the return gets rid of this error.

Comment: It can not be related to the `return`. Your return just terminates the function

Comment: I didn't think so. I was just pointing out that it does not throw that error WHEN i have the return in there.

Comment: Maybe when an item except the first has `undefined`, so when you have return it does not reach to that element, but when you remove it iterates and reaches

Comment: I'm a bit confused then, since its saying the `newInv[i + 1]` is not defined. But if I change it to `newInv[i++]` it says `newInv[i]` meaning the one before it, is undefined. 

So I'm not sure why it would be saying that either of those are undefined, since `i` is declared right before it at a var.

Comment: `i++` will use `i` then increment, `i+1` will add just `1` to the `i`'s value, but not change the actual `i`

Comment: Yeah, but even after changing it it still says that it's undefined.